# Run parallel functions in Pytorch with a single GPU

Tags: python, multithreading, pytorch, gpu

I've succeeded to run several pytorch CNN classifications in parallel running several notebooks (=kernels) almost at the same time.

It has optimized the GPU memory: A single classification only use a third of the memory limit but the RAM usage is greater because every notebook must have all libraries loaded.

That's why I want to run several parallel classifications using the multiprocessing function, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as pool:
    # execute tasks, block until all completed
    pool.map(pytorch_classification, [param1,param2])
```

The kernel never stop running.

When I stop the kernel, it seems that the pool worker doesn't work as expected. Here is a code sample:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 384, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
KeyboardInterrupt
Process ForkPoolWorker-160:
Process ForkPoolWorker-158:
Process ForkPoolWorker-159:
Process ForkPoolWorker-157:
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Does the python multiprocessing library only works with CPUs?

What is the best solution to run parallel pytorch functions using a single GPU?

Answer (score -2):

This is issue is being solved thanks to server management librairies like GUnicorn.

In fact, GUnicorn is able to manage parallel queries and set a threshold to avoid the GPU memory being completely used (otherwise the server crashes).

This is still under investigation, I'll update the answer as soon as I have a complete result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).